# Quick acces toolbar keyboard shortcuts

Tags: excel, keyboard-shortcuts

In excel I regularly use the quick acces toolbar. Unfortunatly i can only use the keyboard shortcuts for the numbers 1 to 9.

How can I use the shortcuts from the numbers higher than 9. (eg. 01, 02, 03 etc). 
I have tried the following methods:
Press & release Alt
Press & release 0
Press & release #

Press Alt
Press & release 0
Press & release #
Release Alt

Press & release Alt
Press 0
Press #
Release 0,#

and all other possible variants of the above.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me. For example, to invoke "08":

1. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>, do not release it
2. Press <kbd>0</kbd>
3. Release <kbd>0</kbd>
4. Press <kbd>8</kbd>
5. Release <kbd>8</kbd>
6. The action is invoked
7. Release <kbd>Alt</kbd>

I'm using Excel 2016, though I don't see why it would have changed since Excel 2010.

Comment: Unfortunatly this does not seem to work in Excel 2010 :(